# Want to know how this struct is working?

Tags: solidity

Suppose we have a struct:

```
struct Struct{
    bool num;
}
```

and a mapping:
`mapping(uint256 => uint256) public simpleMapping;`
and a value: `uint256 number = 100`

so what does this line means:

```
Struct storage newStruct = simpleMapping[number]  // newStruct is storage pointer of Struct
```

As we know we can set a value of mapping by `mappingName[key] = value`, so is it similar to : `simpleMapping[number] = Struct storage newStruct`??? If no, then what actually this :`Struct storage newStruct = simpleMapping[number]` means??

Answer (score 0):

I think the correct way to initialize your struct would be:

```
Struct storage newStruct = Struct(simpleMapping[number])
```

Hope it helps!